# debugging c++ code with dap-mode in Emacs does not display std::variables (e.g., vector, map, etc) correctly. Any idea to solve this problem?

Tags: c++, debug

When I debug c++ code in dap-mode with Emacs, the std::variables, such as vector and map, always have values, **[0]: std**, shown in the local variable area. Does anybody know what is going on?

I am on Mac 10.15.4 and Emacs 27.0.91. lldb-mi is used for debugging.

Thanks.